# How can I add watermark and set the output bitrate and video size, also doing bulk using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing, mp4

I was able to add watermark to multiple video using

```
for %%a in ("*.ts") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i  logoCopy.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40" "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

And now I'm trying to set the output to be 1920x1080 and the bitrate to 30000 and add watermark at the same time.

can anyone help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is

```
for %%a in ("*.ts") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i logoCopy.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40,scale=hd1080,setsar=1" -b:v 30M "Logo\%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it work great,
But if I want to change the output size to less than 1920x1080 what I should put?

Comment: `scale=width:height`